# M2 Frontend goes blank after choosing any theme

Tags: magento2, theme

I have imported a M1 installation into M2.

Changing the theme under `Stores > Configuration > General > Design` from the default setting `-- No Theme --` to ANYTHING breaks the frontend completely. All pages return:

```
Array
(
)
```

regardless of what page is loaded. Even if I revert to `-- No Theme --`, no page loads. Nothing appears in `debug.log` or `system.log`, there are no mysql or Apache errors. PHP log only reports `Unable to initialize module` for a handful of modules, but its been spitting those out regardless of my theme problem.

The only way I can 'fix' this is by restoring the database from a backup. Does anyone have a clue whats going on?

Comment: I can set individual pages to any theme, and they apply and work correctly. CMS, product, and category pages can each be set a theme. But trying to apply the theme to the store breaks the whole front end.

Answer (score 0):

If you just delete everything in the theme table then reload any page, magento will run through it's process to determine what themes are installed and it will then pick up your theme and add it to that table. I'm not sure why it doesn't get automatically added but none the less, that should solve your problem without having to delete the entire database.

Comment: The problem is even if I choose `Magento Luma` or `Magento Blank` the same problem occurs. Could not truncate table `theme` because of a foreign key in `layout_link`. So as expected, when I deleted `theme` rows individually, caused a new error on the front end.